# Sign of fundamental unit in real quadratic number fields with 1 mod 4 discriminant factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field of discriminant $D$ with fundamental unit $\varepsilon$. Further, I want to assume that each positive factor $n$ of $D$ satisfies $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. (For other cases I have enough information concerning my question, hence we do not need to discuss them here.)

Now let us write $D=p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$ as product of primes. Is the sign of $N(\varepsilon)$ well understood in terms of the primes? What I know is that

- for $k=1$ we have $N(\varepsilon)=-1$,
- for $k=2$ and $(p_1/p_2)=-1$ we have $N(\varepsilon)=-1$.

What happens if $k=2$ and $(p_1/p_2)=1$? What happens for $k>2$?

Edit: Some examples for the case $D=pq$ with $(p/q)=1$ ordered by discriminant:

- $D = 5 \cdot 29$, $N(\varepsilon)=-1$
- $D = 5 \cdot 41$, $N(\varepsilon)=+1$
- $D = 13 \cdot 17$, $N(\varepsilon)=+1$
- $D = 5 \cdot 61$, $N(\varepsilon)=+1$
- $D = 13 \cdot 29$, $N(\varepsilon)=+1$
- $D = 5 \cdot 89$, $N(\varepsilon)=-1$
- $D = 5 \cdot 101$, $N(\varepsilon)=+1$

Comment: What is the argument for $k=1$?

Comment: @reuns There are many proofs. For example it follows from genus theory. The genus group has cardinality $2^{k-1}$ and having a trivial genus group implies for the ring of integers to have a negative norm unit.

Comment: @reuns  the case $k=1$ is in Mordell, Diophantine Equations, page 55. The simple argument works  for $D=pq$  when $(p|q) = (q|p) = -1.$  There is a fixed percentage   of $-1$ when $p,q$ are mutual residues.

Comment: I see, the two cases I mention are in the question.

Comment: You wrote that you want to "assume that each factor $n$ of $D$ satisfies $n \equiv 1\bmod 4$". Surely you meant that you want to assume each *prime* factor of $D$ is $1 \bmod 4$. After all, $-1$ is always a factor and $-1 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: @reuns for prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{p}]$ let $x+y\sqrt{p}>1$ be least unit $> 1$ s.t. $x^2-py^2=1$, with $x, y$ in $\mathbf Z^+$. By $x^2 \equiv y^2+1 \bmod 4$, if $y$ odd, then $x^2 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$: no. So $y$ even, $x$ odd. By $py^2=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$, $p(y/2)^2 = (x+1)/2 \cdot (x-1)/2$, so RHS uses consec. int: coprime.  One is $m^2$, other is $pn^2$. If $(x+1)/2=m^2,(x-1)/2=pn^2$, then $m^2-pn^2=1$ and $m \leq m^2=(x+1)/2<x$, so $m+n\sqrt{p}$ is unit $>1$ and smaller than $x+y\sqrt{p}$: contradicts minimality. So $(x+1)/2=pn^2,(x-1)/2=m^2$, making $m^2 - pn^2 = -1$.

Comment: @KCd Come on. I meant each positive factor of $D$. I don't care if they are prime or not but of course it doesn't matter. It is equivalent.

Comment: @KCd Thanks a lot, great insight for why the question has good chances to be complicated (the argument is elementary but it mixes local and global considerations)